# What causes stuff to accumulate in the SVN working copy tmp dirs?

Tags: svn

I have an automated process that does a lot of SVN operations via a large (80GB) sparse checkout tree.

For performance reasons we store this checkout in a RAM drive so we are very sensitive about its size.

Recently I've noticed that non trivial amounts of stuff are accumulating in the .svn/tmp directories.

So far I've been cleaning them out by running SVN cleanup on them. This is rather tedious as I have to offline the system before doing it.

So with a view to solving the problem at the source, my actual question is what is this stuff, where is it coming from and can it be prevented?